# Are the roots of cherry trees dangerous to house foundations?

Tags: fruit-trees, roots

We have a fruiting cherry tree which is 18 months old.  It's planted quite close to the house.  Are the roots dangerous to the property?

Answer (score 5):

Wild cherry trees like the pin cherry and the bird cherry have quite surprising root systems.  The roots can extend out way past the drip line in search of water and nutrients.

Your foundation is not in danger from the cherry tree.  I answered a similar question [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/5787/499).

However a fruiting cherry tree can get quite large depending on the root stock.  I would not recommend planting a tree within 10 feet of a house, twenty if you have the room. You can have problems with

- tree branches rubbing on the house
- fruit attracting wasps or other animals
- and wind storms could break off branches and cause damage to your house